# A new QBASIC IDE, (21st century one)

Tags: ide, editor, basic, qbasic

I'm looking for a modern IDE/Compiler that supports QBASIC programs and has the same or almost similar syntax as of QBASIC. I want to stay as close to Qbasic as possible in terms of syntax, style, and flow. No windowed-based / visual-style languages like Visual Basic. It just needs to have text-based or at least focus on text-based programming.

I'm not looking for opinions on alternatives, like Python or Ruby. My goal is to find an updated form of Qbasic, or something modern that's very similar to QBasic. I know QBASIC can work natively (no full screen) and via DOSBOX in newer windows. But I want something that compiles for modern OSes and that has some sort of syntax highlighting in it.

Thank You

Comment: Why QBASIC of all things?

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question. There is an audience looking for an updated form of Qbasic, not an alternative language altogether. The author is specific in the need for something as close to Qbasic as possible, with support for Qbasic programs.

Comment: QB64 is exactly the thing you are looking for, it has the same kind of IDE and supports the same syntax - it is cross platform and can run things natively and has it's own web/cloud version too.  - Note if this has been open I would've given it as the answer, it was closed saying it will spark debate - in fact QB64 is so close to a right answer I don't think it's the case (if you download the native version the UI is very very close to the original).

Comment: I don't see this as "not constructive" - I want an updated IDE too. Something along the lines of a Visual Studio extension for QBasic!

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at **[FreeBASIC](http://www.freebasic.net/)**. It's an open source compiler and available for Windows, Linux and DOS platforms. Its licenses are GPL and partly LGPL.

On the one hand its syntax is similar to QBasic. For an even better compatibility to legacy QBasic programs it offers a **QB compatibility mode**, which can be enabled using the command line switch `-lang qb` (see [the compiler dialects page in the wiki](http://www.freebasic.net/wiki/wikka.php?wakka=CompilerDialects)) or a preprocessor directive. So you can see it as an unofficial successor of QB.

On the other hand it adds quite a lot of new features to the traditional BASIC world, like for example

- OOP (including inheritance),
- DirectX based 2D graphics,
- support for OpenGL,
- pointers,
- network / internet programming with WinSock etc.,
- bindings for many libraries including curl, BASS, MySQL's C-API, ...

There are a few IDEs available for FreeBASIC. So you're free to choose the one you like most:

- [FBIde](http://fbide.freebasic.net/)
- [FBEdit](https://fbedit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/fbedit/Release/FbEdit.zip)
- [Firefly Visual Designer for FreeBASIC](http://www.planetsquires.com/firefly_freebasic.html)

Furthermore, [Geany](http://geany.org/) as a versatile editor has built-in support for FreeBASIC. Its syntax highlighting also works reasonable for QB source codes.

All the IDEs and editors mentioned in this posting are either free open source software or at least freeware.

An alternative to FreeBASIC is [QB64](http://www.qb64.net/). It is nearer to QB (more similar) but it doesn't offer a modern/graphical UI.